# multi dimentional session array

Tags: php, session

```
session_1.php

<?php session_start();
$_SESSION[0]['uid'] = 1;
$_SESSION[0]['uname'] = "n1";

$_SESSION[1]['uid'] = 2;
$_SESSION[1]['uname'] = "n2";
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>"; die;

header("location:session_2.php");
?>



session_2.php
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);echo "</pre>";
?>
```

some how I can't get values stored in session back. Can anyone tell the reason?

Comment: Any errors? make sure `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is called

Comment: just quote the numbers - $_SESSION['0']

Comment: Is there echoed correct in session_1.php file ?

Comment: whats the output?? array()? or an error?

Comment: echo is working fine in session_1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the comments at http://dk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php according to them, keys at the root level must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION keys at the root level must be valid variable names.

Hope it will help.

Check now with these little changes:-

```
session_1.php

<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['v0']['uid'] = 1;
$_SESSION['v0']['uname'] = "n1";

$_SESSION['v1']['uid'] = 2;
$_SESSION['v1']['uname'] = "n2";


header("location:session_2.php");
?>



session_2.php
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);echo "</pre>";
?>
```